# Changing the function in the text box is not changing the graph

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

I am attempting to create a fiddle which can allow me to change the graph through and input text showing below the graph. I am using jsxgraph library for that.

http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wiki/index.php/Change_Equation_of_a_Graph#JavaScript_Part

Above is the example which is working when you change the function in the text shown graph also changes.

Same example I am trying with the fiddle. But it is not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/me55dw4h/30/

initial code:

```
board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box', {boundingbox: [-6, 12, 8, -6], axis: true});
eval("function f(x){ return "+document.getElementById("eingabe").value+";}");
graph = board.create('functiongraph', [function(x){ return f(x); },-10, 10]);
```

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a jsfiddle-specific problem. If the declaration of the function `doIt` is changed to

```
doIt = function (){
  //redefine function f according to the current text field value
  eval("function f(x){ return "+document.getElementById("eingabe").value+";}");
  //change the Y attribute of the graph to the new function 
  graph.Y = function(x){ return f(x); };
  //update the graph
  graph.updateCurve();
  //update the whole board
  board.update();
};
```

instead of

```
function doIt() {
     ...
}
```

then the example runs.

But let me emphasize that meanwhile JSXGraph comes with it's own parser *JessieCode* (see https://github.com/jsxgraph/JessieCode), which allows the input of common math syntax instead of JavaScript syntax. That means, instead of `Math.sin(x)` the user may just input `sin(x)`. Additionally, there is the power operator `^`, i.e. instead of `Math.pow(x,2)` it is possible to type `x^2`.

A minimal example using *JessieCode* for function plotting looks like this, see https://jsfiddle.net/eLs83cs6/

```
board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box', {boundingbox: [-6, 12, 8, -6], axis: true});

doPlot = function() {
    var txtraw = document.getElementById('input').value, // Read user input
        f = board.jc.snippet(txtraw, true, 'x', true), // Parse input with JessieCode
        curve;

    board.removeObject('f'); // Remove element with name f
    curve = board.create('functiongraph', [f, -10, 10], {name:'f'});
};

doPlot();
```

Ann additional side effect is that the parsing of the math syntax with *JessieCode* prevents XSS attacks which would be easily possible if the users are allowed to supply arbitrary JavaScript code as input.